# Swift bracket notation after property

Tags: swift

I see this code and variants of it

```
var myVar: CGFloat {get set}
```

what does the `{get set}` part mean?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It means that your variable implements a getter and a setter, if you don't want people to set your variable to another value you would use:

```
var myVar: CGFloat {get}
```

However if you don't want people to be able to read the value from your variable you could declare as

```
var myVar: CGFloat {set}
```

You can also add restrictions and/or behaviours to get and set:

```
  var _myVar:Int = 2
  var myVar{
   get {
     return _myVar * 2 //Always returns the double of the value set
   }
   set (newVal) {
     if newVal >= 0 { //limit the variable to positive numbers
       _myVar = newVal
     } else {
       println('error: myVar has to be greater than zero')
     }
   }
```

Of course those are simple examples and it can get very complex depending on each one needs.

You can also use `private(set)` and `internal(set)` to change the access level of each property. As per apple's example:

```
struct TrackedString {
    private(set) var numberOfEdits = 0
    var value: String = "" {
        didSet {
            numberOfEdits++
        }
    }
}
```

You can learn more about getter, setter, computer properties and other in [apple documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/Properties.html) and [And in this other document](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/AccessControl.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014097-CH41-ID18)

I hope that helps you!

Comment: if you don't want people to set the variable to another name or to another value?

Comment: @noobsmcgoobs to another value, sorry I fix that

Answer (score 0):

These are computed properties/variables and they allow for variables to compute values for the getter or setter rather than a standard variable.

> The getter is used to read the value, and the setter is used to write the value. The setter clause is optional, and when only a getter is needed, you can omit both clauses and simply return the requested value directly, as described in Read-Only Computed Properties. But if you provide a setter clause, you must also provide a getter clause.
>
> The setter name and enclosing parentheses is optional. If you provide
>   a setter name, it is used as the name of the parameter to the setter.
>   If you do not provide a setter name, the default parameter name to the
>   setter is newValue, as described in Shorthand Setter Declaration.

[Declarations](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/Declarations.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014097-CH34-ID351)

Comment: getter and set can also be applied to stored properties not just computer properties as per apple documentation "Getters and Setters... This rule applies to stored properties as well as computed properties"